# How do you pronounce the Star Wars universe curse word, "fierfek"?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, pronunciation

**How do you pronounce the Star Wars universe curse word, *"fierfek"*?**

> **Fierfek** was a Huttese slang word that meant "hex" or "curse," but was commonly accepted to mean "poison" by non-Huttese-speaking races, most commonly Trandoshans. During the Clone Wars, it was adopted by clone commandos as a curse word. Boba Fett and Han Solo would later use it during the Second Galactic Civil War.

([source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fierfek))

It's commonly mistaken for the Mandalorian language, but official Star Wars says **fierfek** is clearly Huttese. 

I'm not sure if **fierfek** is pronounced as FUR-fek? FEAR-fek? FIRE-fek?

It's spelled similarly to Food Network personality Guy Fieri's last name so maybe it is pronounced like FEE-AIR-fek? Do you roll the "R"?

Comment: I have nothing to back this up, but I'd pronounce it somewhere between fear-feck and fur-fek.

Comment: @Kevin: And the German "verfickt". `:-o`

Comment: I think its more like far-FESS because of the way the Hutts speak.  I also have nothing to back it up in universe though.  It also rolls off the tongue better imo and sounds like an easy to say explicative.

Comment: @Kevin - you are correct, Sir.

Comment: @user3072 - I thought my answer was pretty convincing. Is there anything additional you'd like to see before offering an acceptance?

Comment: Gah! I keep glancing over this question on the front page and immediately reading it as [_Férfiakt_](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0830896/). Ruddy Hungarians.

Answer (score 6):

The word fierfek is used *repeatedly* in the game "[Star Wars : Republic Commando](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Republic_Commando)". 
You can hear it at the 08:37 mark in the walkthrough video [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1atx9y_star-wars-republic-commando-walkthrough-part-9-go-fierfek-yourself_videogames).

The closest I can get to a written pronunciation guide is '**fear-feck** (or "fɪə-fɛk" if you want to get technical).

---

UPDATE: I [asked](https://twitter.com/karentraviss/status/619441621092945925) Karen Traviss. She didn't know.

> **Q.** *Quick question. How do you pronounce fierfek?*
>
> **A. [Karen Traviss]** *Not sure. (Not my invention.) FEAR-feck?*

Answer (score 1):

I've read the books that the game is based off of, Republic Commando by Karen Traviss, and since the first book "Hard Contact" was published in 2004, I believe that it came before the game, which was released in 2005.

Anyways, Mrs. Traviss wrote it at "Fire-fek", so I believe the pronunciation is phonetic, and there may have been a mistake in the voice-acting for the game.

Anyways, that's just my contribution and how I pronounce and spell it at least.

Comment: I spoke to Karen Traviss earlier today. She said she wasn't sure :-)